# How to connect to remote gRPC service

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I created a gRPC service and client in C# .NET Core 3.1. When I deploy the service to localhost, I can connect to it without a problem. But when I publish the service to a IIS via WebDeploy and start it there I cannot connect to it.

For a local deployment, the channel is initialized as follows:

`var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");`

For the remote deployment I change it to the following value, since it starts as a HTTP service on `http://localhost:5000` on the remote machine (which I also failed to find out how to change - I would prefer it to start as a HTTPS service):

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://1.2.3.4:5000");
```

`1.2.3.4` is the IP of the remote machine, which I am able to ping. I also created a firewall rule to allow all inbound traffic on inbound port `5000`.

The client application fails on the first remote call with the error message

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

I fail to understand which measures I have to take to create a connection to the remote service. All example gRPC code I have found so far uses `localhost` as a deploy point and did not help me figure out the root cause of my problem.

Any help or pointers towards what I must have missed are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From [Tutorial: Create a gRPC client and server in ASP.NET Core](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909), a warning almost at the end of the article, says

> ASP.NET Core gRPC is not currently supported on Azure App Service or IIS. The HTTP/2 implementation of Http.Sys does not support HTTP response trailing headers which gRPC relies on...

Please refer to [gRPC in production](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/grpc-in-production) for ways to run your gRPC service in production.